# symbol of a newly created point moves to a different place at different zoom level

Tags: qgis, symbology, point

I connect QGIS to an Oracle database. I add a point object on my map in QGIS and the new point is shown in the map, so that is great. But once I zoom out the map the symbol of the point moves to another place, when i click the symbol there is no attribute of the point can be shown so i think it is just the symbol becomes crazy.

I have closed everything and loaded the point layer from the database again but the problem is just the same.

I have checked the point in another map software and it looks normal.

Can it be a bug or something i have done wrong?

This problem just occurs in certain area of the map. If I create a point far away from the problematic area then it is normal again.

[image: the green point moves when i zoom out the map or panning to another place]

Comment: please add an example of the data point and screen shots showing what happens